# How to sketch $0 \lt \text{arctan} \Bigl(\frac{y}{x}\Bigr) \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have an exercise:

Let $f:(0,\infty) \times \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^2,(x,y) \rightarrow \Biggl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \text{arctan}\Bigl(\frac{y}{x}\Bigr)\Biggr)$ Find and sketch $f^{-1}((0,1) \times(0 , \frac{\pi}{2}))$.

**What I tried so far:**

$f^{-1}((0,1) \times (0, \frac{\pi}{2}))=  \{(x,y) \in \Bigl((0 ,\infty) \times \Bbb R \Bigr) : \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \in (0,1) \cap \text{arctan}\Bigl(\frac{y}{x}\Bigr) \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})\}$

So for the first condition:

$0 \lt \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \lt 1$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x^2+y^2 \lt 1$. This is the region inside the unit circle without the boundaries.

And for the second condition:

$0 \lt \text{arctan} \Bigl(\frac{y}{x}\Bigr) \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $0 \lt \frac{y}{x} \lt \infty$.

Is this correct? If so, then how do I graph this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions tell you that

1. $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1$;
2. $0<\arctan(y/x)<\pi/2$.

Since $x\in(0,\infty)$, the first condition becomes $x^2+y^2<1$. The second condition forces $y>0$ (because $x>0$ by assumption).

So you get a the inner part of a quarter circle.